# What is the difference between enhancement and proposal in bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, issue-tracking

When creating new issue on bitbucket I can select, among other, `proposal` and `enhancement`. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A proposal is a request for a *new* feature, whereas an enhancement enhances an *existing* feature.